# How to handle this hard disk backup

Tags: hard-drive, backup, images

Inserting a larger ram into my laptop causes windows to BSOD frequently, and going back to the old ram does not fix the issue once it is triggered. The only solution is a clean install of windows with the other ram (I have spent tens of hours on this situation) I know that both rams are working.

I have a new driver that gives me reason to believe that the larger ram might work now. I want to try it, but I don't have to end up having to reinstall windows.

What would be the most robust way to backup my entire C: and restore it if a problem occurs?

Comment: Do you have another 2.5" laptop HDD available?  If so, remove your current drive, replace with the spare and reinstall Windows on the spare drive to see if the problem reoccurs.

Comment: Such a great idea. Would it work with a regular desktop HDD? I could buy a sata extension cable etc maybe?

Comment: Yeah that would work.  Sorry I thought this was a laptop you were dealing with for some reason

Comment: Prolly cuz you state that the issue is with a laptop.

Comment: Wait I'm confused, where would a regular desktop come into play if the issue is with a laptop?  What exactly are you asking "will it work" about?  Obviously you can't stick a 3.5" hard drive in a laptop, so please give some more details on what you are trying to do and how you plan on doing it

Comment: I was hoping I could "connect" a 3.5" hdd into a laptop. The sata connections looked the same to me?

Answer (score 0):

I would boot up in a Linux Live System (for example Ubuntu) and preform a "dd" command [like this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_cloning) to an external drive.
If something goes wrong, you can restore your complete drive.